# Break-even analysis

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose you have a collection of items ( we will call apples and oranges ) which are purchased each day for dollars (USD) and later exchanged for an arbitrary value system, called (foo).

- An apple *always* sells for `100 foo`,  and an orange always sells for `200 foo` no matter what.
- Today's purchase price for an apple is `$1.50` USD and `$3.00` for an orange. Those prices can and will vary wildly depending on the day.
- Additionally: 
  For every matched pair of apples and oranges, you receive an bonus of 50 foo.

What is a formula that will find the optimal ratio of apples and oranges each day, that will minimize the cost in USD, if your target sell price is `60,000 foo`?

---

This is a real world break even point problem I've run into while setting up a side business.
So far I have the following formulas which only work if number of apples = number of oranges which isn't necessarily the most cost effective.

y = `60,000`
f = `200` + `100 + 50`
d = `$1.50` + `$3.50`
t = y / f
n = t * d